# How to check if a person exsist and then insert into another table using pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Create an anonymous PL/SQL block, which looks for an employee by last name based on a SQL parameter (e.g. &variable) that the user responds to with a valid last_name in the EMPLOYEES table (i.e. King, or Kochhar, or De Haan, or Hunold, or Ernst, etc….…).  If the employee last_name exists in the EMPLOYEES table, then insert into the OUTPUT_LOG table, the following string:
'Employee is  is Found'.  Test your PL/SQL block by checking the content of the OUTPUT_LOG table.  You should find the string the you inserted in the OUTPUT_LOG table.

employee table has these columns
EMPLOYEE_ID ,
FIRST_NAME ,
LAST_NAME ,
EMAIL ,
PHONE_NUMBER ,
HIRE_DATE ,
JOB_ID ,
SALARY ,
COMMISSION_PCT ,
MANAGER_ID ,
DEPARTMENT_ID

output_log table only has one column VARCHAR2(250) called data and id column as PRIMARY KEY

I am struggling to figure check if the name exist in the table. I thought about using

```
 begin 
SELECT e.LAST_NAME as LAST_NAME, o.data
INTO OUTPUT_LOG
FROM EMPLOYEES as e, OUTPUT_LOG as O  
WHERE e.employee_id = o.id
 end;
```

but i dont think it would be wise and make sense to do so
[image: EMPLOYEES TABLE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this appears to be a homework question, I'm not going to solve it all for you but (to help you on your way) you could just use `SELECT ... INTO` and if a row is not found it will raise a `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception which you can catch (and use this to bypass the `INSERT`). Something like this:

```
DECLARE
  p_found NUMBER(1,0);
BEGIN
  SELECT 1
  INTO   p_found
  FROM   Employees
  WHERE  ROWNUM = 1
  AND    last_name = 'King'; -- replace with your where condition

  -- then do the insert here (since it will only reach this point if
  -- a row was found).
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
END;
/
```

Comment: thanks that just all the information I need since I do want to figure out the information on my own.